# Mockito: how to mock method with the result depending on one of its parameters?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, jooq

Is there a way to pass params to mocked function and use that param value inside. Example (**notice name as param**):

```
Mockito.when(clientRepo.registerNewClient(Mockito.any(String.class) as name))
    .thenReturn(
        dslContext
            .insertInto(CLIENT)
            .set(CLIENT.CLIENT_NAME, name)
            .execute());
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: maybe you want to use a Spy instead of a Mock for that case.

Comment: Is `dslContext.insertInto(...` what the real clientRepo object does? If so, @Alfredo is correct, spy is the way to go. If not, you could consider wiring in a test implementation of clientRepo's interface that does what you want in your test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `thenAnswer`, and get your argument from the `InvocationOnMock`.

```java
final Repo clientRepo = Mockito.mock(Repo.class);
Mockito.when(clientRepo.registerNewClient(Mockito.any(String.class)))
    .thenAnswer(
        (Answer<Client>)
            invocationOnMock -> new Client(
                invocationOnMock
                    .getArgumentAt(0, String.class)
                    .toUpperCase()
            )
    );
Assertions.assertEquals(
    clientRepo.registerNewClient("fff"), new Client("FFF")
);
```